# 2 or more functions cannot execute in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, iframe

I have product grid and each product calls javascript with its unique ID for opening iframe window.
When calling the first one it works but when calling the second it does nothing.
I will have around 20 products that need to call that script.

I want if it's possible when calling the second iframe, the first to close and the second to appear and so on.

Here is the script:

```js
function init() {

  test = true;

  document.getElementById('go<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>').onclick = function() {
    ifr = document.createElement('iframe');
    ifr.setAttribute('src', this.href);
    ifr.src = this.href;
    ifr.setAttribute('id', 'iframe_a<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');

    if (test == true) {
      ifr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 'complete<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>') {}
      }
      document.getElementById('iframe_a_container<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>').appendChild(ifr);
      test = false;
    }
    return false;
  }
}

window.addEventListener ?
  window.addEventListener('load', init, false) :
  window.attachEvent('onload', init);
```

The Iframe code:

```html
<div id="iframe_a_container<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>">  </div>
```

and the button code:

```html
<a id="go<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>" href="index.php?route=product/quickview&amp;product_id=<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>">Quick View</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you declared ifr before (outside of the onclick); if not, you should do it (So you have a reference to access it) and try if this modified onclick works:

```
document.getElementById('go<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>').onclick = function() {
    $(ifr).remove(); // Remove it from the screen
    ifr = null;
    ifr = document.createElement('iframe');
    ifr.setAttribute('src', this.href);
    ifr.src = this.href;
    ifr.setAttribute('id', 'iframe_a<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');

    if (test == true) {
      ifr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 'complete<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>') {}
      }
      document.getElementById('iframe_a_container<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>').appendChild(ifr);
      test = false;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: With your method, the button just acts like a href with no function.
The script stops working. It is inside of the onclick. Here is the working script http://www.petite-style.com/tea (quick view button below the products)

Comment: tried with onmouseover and out it works with your code little bit modified but it does not do the job.